# How to pass both groovy variable and javascript value to grails controller?

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

```
<td><g:field type="number" name="deadlineFT" value="${selectedMilestone.deadlineFT}"
            onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'updateMilestone', params: [id: selectedMilestoneID, item:'deadlineFT', value: this.value])}"/> Months</td>
```

`selectedMilestoneID` is a `groovy` variable. The above code is not working since `this.value` cannot be recognised by groovy. However if I use `params: '\'value\'+this.value`, it cannot get `selectedMilestoneID`.

**Is there any way to get both values?**

Comment: remoteFunction is deprecated in grails 2.4, use jquery ajax or something similar for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<g:field type="number" name="deadlineFT" value="${selectedMilestone.deadlineFT}"
       onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'updateMilestone',
       params: "'id=${selectedMilestoneID}&value='+this.value")}"/>
```